# ERROR java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer al utilizar SeekbarPreference en Kotlin

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer error al utilizar un SeekBar Preference con kotlin.

```
<SeekBarPreference
        android:key="profile_weight"
        android:title="@string/profile_weight"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile_weight"
        android:max="@integer/profile_max_weight"
        app:min="@integer/profile_min_weight"
        android:defaultValue="60"
        app:showSeekBarValue="true" />
```

Existe alguna solución en código KOTLIN para solucionar el error?

Probando, me ha funcionado sin problemas utilizando una SettingsActivity en lugar de un SettingsFragment

Comment: ¿En qué código **Java** ocurre el error? Pulsa en [edit] para mostrarlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano  no utilizo código Java, utilizo Kotlin. Y el error parece estar en el xml, aunque creo que la solución puede estar en castear el valor que devuelve a un Int en la clase asociada a ese fragmento, pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: El problema es al obtener el valor de SeekBarPreference @IvándeLucasRogero , agrega el código Kotlin de como estas oteniendo el valor